# BuildFire Custom Plugin Navigation

Tags: buildfire

We have a Custom Plugin that was created and is connected with a live app. There seems to be an error with navigating back to the main page of the app once in the Custom Plugin created. Forcing the user to close the app and reopen to access other areas in the app.

What would be causing the main navigation with the app being nonfunctional here?[Broken navigation highlighted in orange of custom plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neqCq.jpg)

Comment: Are you using Breadcrumbs https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Breadcrumbs  or are you hijacking `buildfire.navigation.onBackButtonClick` https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Navigation#buildfirenavigationonbackbuttonclick-function

Comment: We did not touched  build fire's context so far, our sft app works with angular routing only

Comment: What I would suggest is then handle the backbutton event here https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Navigation#buildfirenavigationonbackbuttonclick-function and see if it's actually triggering and how the event bubbles up. If its not triggering, then create a simple hello-world tedt plugin and see if you're having the same issues. If no issues are found in the test plugin then its definitely in your angular navigation code. If the problem persists in the test plugin then you may have a corrupt SDK.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback above, we have an updated plugin were trying to upload to take place of the existing plugin that is having navigation issues. It seems the dev portal is stating the plugin name is already in use, from my understanding the new plugin zip is a different name though.

Comment: I was able to go through the Update option to upload the new version to take place of the connected Custom Plugin with the live app. It seems the issue still continues with navigating out of the Custom plugin back to the main page of the app though. Looking for suggestions to solve urgently.

Comment: Hello, we made an update with the plugin today and all seems to be resolved with the Navigation issue that was occurring. Thank you for time and assistance.